# EF null check on group by clause

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework

I need the following code to work on any IQueryable, even if the underlying repository is just an array. This throws an NRE during my unit test with a fake in memory array backing store. Obviously because `y` might be null, especially after a left outer join, `y` can't help itself but be null.

```
var x = from y in SomeIQueryable
        group y by y.someForeignKey
        into z
        select z;
```

I have changed it to the following.

```
var x = from y in SomeIQueryable
        group y by y != null ? y.someForeignKey : null
        into z
        select z;
```

Will setting the group by like the above cause any issue when run against an actual SQL backing store?

Comment: Don't use array in unit tests and you will be fine. When changing real implementation with array or collection you are also changing Linq provider = your unit test doesn't test your real code. You have found a situation where unit test fail due to different nature of Linq-to-entities provider but more common situation is passing unit test and failing runtime code which makes the unit test useless and unreliable.

Comment: @LadislavMrnka Your comment is useful, but it doesn't really apply unless the sole point of the test is to check that the query works.

Comment: @hvd: That is why I wrote it as a comment and not as an answer. Btw. checking that query works means checking it with a provider you want to use in the real code - that means not with fake.

Comment: @LadislavMrnka Yes, that's what I meant too, if the point is to check that the query works, then don't use a different provider. But a unit test that, for example, checks that a correct reminder is generated for unpaid invoices, may happen to perform a query to retrieve the invoices, but that's not the point of the unit test, the point of the unit test is that the retrieved invoices result in the correct documents/whatever. That test can still be useful with in-memory data.

Comment: @hvd: In such case the query should not be part of tested method because your method has now two concerns: the logic to check the reminder and the logic to execute a query. You can't test each concern separately when you put them in the same method and you need to test the same method and as a result you need an integration test for the same method to test the real query = you are testing the same method twice.

Comment: @LadislavMrnka I see the point you're making. That involves refactoring the code, it's not an option when you're adding a unit test for existing code that should remain unchanged, but I think I agree in almost all other cases.

Comment: The reason in memory array was used is for isolation purposes. If I go back to using an actual SQL store, I'd break that isolation, and the resulting unit test will turn into integration test & be very fragile.

Answer (score 0):

My experience with such checks is that EF does support them, will translate them to correct SQL. However, the generated SQL will include the null check and at least on SQL Server, the query will perform somewhat worse. For complex queries, it becomes noticeable.

But as long as the second form performs well enough in your queries, it's probably good enough.

Comment: This is what I was afraid of.

Answer (score 0):

In general, such modification it should not cause any problems. If it does, you will gen an exception claiming that the underlying provider cannot transalte the query into SQL for some reason. Yep, any issues will be provider-specific and noone is able to answer it in general.

For the newser T-SQL (SqlServer), it should work OK as you can (IIRC) group-by over computed columns - and for the SQL the expression you are providing is exactly this: a computed column.

Howeve , yo umust be very careful with other traps, for eaxmple the null checks behave differently when passed by-value and by-variable..

If the query contains exactly `x != null` then it will be translated to `x NOT NULL` on the SQL backend. But if you capture a value by-name, even local, ie. `int? blah = null; .... from ... x != blah` then EF will translate it "incorrectly" as `x <> @param` with `@param = NULL` the code will not work as wanted..

There are more of such slight nuances of C#<->SQL translations.. However, I do not see anything dangerous in the exact code you provided. It just looks OK. If you try it once and if it does not throw aything like `NotSupportedException`, than you can assume it will work properly. The linq providers usually throw exceptions of that class if they are not able to translate some expressions properly.

Comment: Now try it with `group by y.Length` and you'll get the NRE that Alwyn is trying to avoid by adding a null check.

Comment: On SQL Server, `GROUP BY (nullable)` works just fine, it groups all the `NULL` values together. The question you linked to says MySQL does the same thing: the question asks how to change that to not do so.

Comment: I've replaced the link. The T-SQL says it fixed that in 2003, but, erm, I'm sure I've hit it a couple of times ago, and it was "yet another weird case" just like with =var when var is null.. It might have been an error in a different place, but this is how I remembered it

Comment: I have grouped by null values on SQL Server 2000, where it also works. That's the oldest version supported by Entity Framework. I'd be interested if you have a system where it reliably fails.

Comment: I cannot specify, it was too long ago, I just do not remember. I worked mostly on mssql 2000/3/5/8, on mysql 4 and some oracle 9/10. It was surely not after 2005, so I guessed 2000 because its T-SQL had many quirks.. If you are sure that it worked there, that means that either I screwed up something else back then, or that I simply remember wrong. Thanks for the information, I'll clean up the post.